# Windows 8 app: accessing local and network files

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I started programming Windows 8 apps in C#, and I need help to figure how to access files from within my app.

Premise: from what I learned till this moment, I know that as standard an app can access only certain folders (such as LocalFolder etc.). One way to overcome this is using a FileOpenPicker once and then use FutureAccessList to access programmatically the file.

Now my situation:

- my pc is connected to a domain network
- my app has the following capabilities: Enterprise Authentication, Internet (Client & Server), Private Networks (Client & Server)
- Let's say that I have a file named **im.jpg** in **C:** and **im2.jpg** in a network share called **share**. I (my domain account) have the access to those files.

How can I access those files from my app without the use of FileOpenPicker? 
Till now, I used WebRequest and WebResponse to download a file from an internet site (no problems), then I used WebRequest and WebResponse to access a file located in the LocalFolder of my app (still no problems), but now, if I do something like this:

```
WebRequest c = WebRequest.Create(@"file://C:\im.jpg");
WebResponse r = await c.GetResponseAsync();
```

I get a System.Net.WebException telling that I'm not authorized to access the file.
How can I use Enterprise Authentication to provide my domain credentials to the app? I didn't find much documentation about this on the MSDN, but from the little I found I think this capability is intended to be used in a situation like this. Also, is WebRequest the right path to follow? Should I try to access those files in other ways?

Thanks, Daniele

Answer (score 2):

No matter, how you try to access the files from a Windows Store app, the permissions still apply, i.e. you can't access a random file on a disk or a file share if a user didn't grant you access before using a `FileOpenPicker` or a `FolderPicker`.

The best you can do is probably getting the user to access the root (of a disk or a share) using a `FolderPicker` and storing a reference to it in `FutureAccessList`. This way you'll be able to access all the files on that drive without any user intervention in the future.

Having a service as a workaround should work for shares (why not just use HTTP to allow file download instead?) but not for the local file system because your app can't access local network resources (i.e. services on localhost) unless you're running it from VS or using `CheckNetIsolation.exe` by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Enterprise Authentication, but opening a file is usually done using [StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefrompathasync.aspx). That also works with UNC path names when you have the permission..

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I explain better: I can use GetFileFromPathAsync only if the string representing the file points to a file the user selected with FileOpenPicker and that has been inserted in FutureAccessList. I also found this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280599/windows-8-metro-app-file-share-access)... I'll try to write a service and see if I can connet to it to ask for a file. Thanks anyway